# Unexpected result on using the different shapes with an ImageButton states

Tags: android, android-selector, android-imagebutton, android-shape

My simple target is to change the background of `ImageButton` on different button states. So, what I have is

**mylayout.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MyActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/idBackground">
    ...
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnCapture"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_photo_selector"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_photo"
        android:padding="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

**ic_photo_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval" >

            <gradient
                android:centerColor="#3311ffed"
                android:centerX="0.5"
                android:centerY="0.5"
                android:endColor="#8011ffed"
                android:gradientRadius="150"
                android:startColor="#2711ffed"
                android:type="radial" />

            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#3300DDFF" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="15dp"
                android:left="15dp"
                android:right="15dp"
                android:top="15dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/capture_button_bg"/>

</selector>
```

**capture_button_bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <gradient
        android:centerColor="#1111ffed"
        android:centerX="0.5"
        android:centerY="0.5"
        android:endColor="#5E11ffed"
        android:gradientRadius="150"
        android:startColor="#0511ffed"
        android:type="radial" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#1100DDFF" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="15dp"
        android:left="15dp"
        android:right="15dp"
        android:top="15dp" />

</shape>
```

**ic_photo.png**(it is transparent image but due to this web site has white background I posted it on black layer)

[image]

So, as you can see, the visual difference between both states (pressed and default) should be just in transparence.
But the design mode as the real devices are showed another result

```
                        Default State              Pressed State
```

My mind really is blocked. Why the default button has the such color difference with the pressed button? As I expected, the difference should be just in transparency mode.

Any ideas? Or may be it's something wrong in my code snippets?

Comment: you can try with imageview.

Comment: In you selector again you are setting  <item android:drawable="@drawable/capture_button_bg"/> which is default. Try replacing it with trasperent color.

Comment: @Ravi It doesn't helped me. Moreover, when I have used `ImageView` instead `ImageButton` the selector has lost its sense (the button now has the static image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of my issue, but it is something strange.

The occasion of the behaviour described above was consisted in using the inline `<shape>` for **pressed state** and the reference to the drawable for **default state**.

**Solutions:**

1) Using the inline `<shape>` both for **pressed state** and **default state**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval" >

            <gradient
                android:centerColor="#3311ffed"
                android:centerX="0.5"
                android:centerY="0.5"
                android:endColor="#8011ffed"
                android:gradientRadius="150"
                android:startColor="#2711ffed"
                android:type="radial" />

            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#3300DDFF" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="15dp"
                android:left="15dp"
                android:right="15dp"
                android:top="15dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval" >

            <gradient
                android:centerColor="#1111ffed"
                android:centerX="0.5"
                android:centerY="0.5"
                android:endColor="#5E11ffed"
                android:gradientRadius="150"
                android:startColor="#0511ffed"
                android:type="radial" />

            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#1100DDFF" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="15dp"
                android:left="15dp"
                android:right="15dp"
                android:top="15dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

2) Using the reference to the drawable for the **pressed state** and the inline `<shape>` for **default state**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/capture_button_bg_pressed"/>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval" >

            <gradient
                android:centerColor="#1111ffed"
                android:centerX="0.5"
                android:centerY="0.5"
                android:endColor="#5E11ffed"
                android:gradientRadius="150"
                android:startColor="#0511ffed"
                android:type="radial" />

            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#1100DDFF" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="15dp"
                android:left="15dp"
                android:right="15dp"
                android:top="15dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

**capture_button_bg_pressed.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

            <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >

                <gradient
                    android:centerColor="#3311ffed"
                    android:centerX="0.5"
                    android:centerY="0.5"
                    android:endColor="#8011ffed"
                    android:gradientRadius="150"
                    android:startColor="#2711ffed"
                    android:type="radial" />

                <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"
                    android:color="#3300DDFF" />

                <padding
                    android:bottom="15dp"
                    android:left="15dp"
                    android:right="15dp"
                    android:top="15dp" />

            </shape>
```

Also, main point is that the **default state** should be followed last (below any other states).

I can't explain why it is so, but it works for me.